# How to use conditional symbols when targeting multiple frameworks correctly (VS2017)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, target, .net-standard

I want to migrate a library project which targeted .NET Framework 4.6.1 to a new one targeting both, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Standard 2.0.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' "> 
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In my current code I use, for example: `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` method; so, I already added a condition in my `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now in my code, I know that I could have something like this:

```
#if NET461
   if (someFolderVar.StartsWith("~/"))
       someFolderVar = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(someFolderVar);
#endif
```

My question:

If later I change my project to target .NET Framework 4.7, will the above code be executed or it will be strictly targeted for .NET Framework 4.6.1 only? What condition to use for 4.6.1 and up?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: You do not need to support .NET Framework 4.6.1 since .NET Standard 2.0 support it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: As for conditional symbols, suggest to refer to serilog:https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Serilog.csproj

Comment: @FeiyuZhou Don't understand what does .NET Standard 2.0 support ? You mean the System.Web or ?

Comment: @Learner .NET Standard support both .NET Core and .NET Framework platforms. For .NET Standard 2.0 it support .NET Framework 4.6.1+. You can read the link to learn the knowledge

Comment: @FeiyuZhou There are things in .Net Framework which are not in NET Standard; this means sometimes the code may differ between the 2

Comment: For dotnet Libraries, i think they're same since .NET Standard defines the common API for all platforms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173464/discussion-between-feiyu-zhou-and-learner).

Comment: The usage of "net461" moniker was a very unfortunate hack to get a beta version of netcore out of the door.  It just doesn't mean what it appears to say, it does **not** mean that you actually target 4.6.1.  It means that you target the full framework version.  You can make the conditional anything you like, its value is not set by the net461 moniker.  Clearly you prefer "NETFULL", so just use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution in this very good [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20). The use of `NETFULL` conditional symbol (from the article, but any name will do) should be a solution:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
  <DefineConstants>NETFULL</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47'">
  <DefineConstants>NETFULL</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then the code:

```
#if NETFULL
if (someFolderVar.StartsWith("~/"))
   someFolderVar = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(someFolderVar);
#endif
```

Comment: The one obvious problem with this is that you still need to explicitly mention all .NET Framework versions in your project file. That's better than mentioning them in your code, but is still problematic for compatibility. Targeting .NET 4.7.2 with this will change the behavior with no indication from the code. I find it hard to imagine nobody at MS has run into issues like this, which makes me think this is by design, although what that design is escapes me. You may be better off halting the build with an error to "please update the conditionals" when an unknown framework is used!

Comment: @JeroenMostert you raised very good points.. thanks, I appreciate!

Comment: Just a sidenote: you can give the `NETFULL`-symbol any name you like, also just `MYCONST`. The constant only exists within your assembly as indicated by the `DefineConstants`-tag within your csproj-file.

Comment: btw. I made open source VS2017 extension, with multi-target (SDK/PackageReference) project template (4.0, 4.5 and Standard 2.0), mostly based on the article Learner referred + some tweaks, like after build copy of the .nupkg to a local path (purpose: updating the local NuGet library). Also, there is tutorial (linked in extension description) discussing further the issue you asked about. The extension: http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=imbVeles.imbACEBasicPack, the tutorial: http://blog.veles.rs/imbace-basicpack-getting-started-draft/